# Geometric interpretation of $q$ in Lens space $L(p,q)$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I know the quotient definition of Lens space: given complex coordinate $z_1,z_2$,
the Lens $L(p,q)$ manifold is defined by the identification $$
(z_1,z_2) \sim (e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}} z_1, e^{\frac{2\pi qi}{p}} z_1)
$$
I also know the definition like in Heegaard decomposition we need to glue the $(1,0)$ circle with $(p,q)$ circle of two $D_2\times S^1$ manifold to construct Lens $L(p,q)$. But it is just not very clear to me what is the meaning of such statement.

I roughly understand what is the meaning of $p$ parameter, because we can calculate the first fundamental group of Lens space $L(p,q)$ which will be $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
But I want to know what is the effect of $q$ on the manifold if $q>1$.
Is it related to any geometric quantities like torsion or something else, such that we might have more intuitive picture to tell the difference between $L(p,1)$ and $L(p,q)$.

Comment: [Possibly duplicate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1186778/272127)